# How to replace one part of list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following data and want to replace only the first part in all sublists by the square root. It can be done by:

```
data = {{49, 35, 14}, {64, 40, 16}, {81, 45, 18}};
t2 = Transpose[{Sqrt /@ data[[All, 1]]}];
t3 = Table[Flatten[AppendTo[t2[[i]], data[[i, 2 ;; 3]]]], {i, 3}]
```

and I get

```
{{7, 35, 14}, {8, 40, 16}, {9, 45, 18}}
```

What is a shorter way using `Replace` or other methods (and/or using patterns)?

Comment: This `data /. {a_Integer, b_Integer, c_Integer} :> {Sqrt[a], b, c}` seems to satisfy your immediate requirement.  Is that the kind of answer you want ?

Comment: `{Sqrt[#[[1]]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data` or 
`{Sqrt[#[[1]]], Sequence @@ Rest@##} & /@ data` or 
`ReplacePart[#, 1 -> Sqrt[#[[1]]]] & /@ data`

Comment: data[[;; , 1]] = Sqrt[data[[;; , 1]]]

Comment: data[[All, 1]] = Sqrt[data[[All, 1]]] .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

```
MapAt[Sqrt, data, {All, 1}]
```

```
Replace[data, {x_, y___} :> {Sqrt[x], y}, {1}]
```

```
data // Query[All, {1 -> Sqrt}]
```

```
SubsetMap[Sqrt, data, {All, 1}]
```

```
ReplacePart[data, {i_, 1} :> Sqrt[data[[i, 1]]]]
```

```
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 1]] = Sqrt[data2[[All, 1]]];
data2
```

Comment: Wow! That gives me material to breed over. Great!

Answer (score 9):

```
☺ = {#^(1/2), ##2} &;

☺ @@@ data
```

> ```
> {{7, 35, 14}, {8, 40, 16}, {9, 45, 18}}
> ```

or

```
☺☺ = {#^(1/2), ##2} & @@@ # &;

☺☺ @ data
```

> ```
> {{7, 35, 14}, {8, 40, 16}, {9, 45, 18}}
> ```

Comment: I can understand your first solution, but what does "@@@ # &" in the second part really mean?

Comment: @user57467, ` foo@@@#&`  _replaces heads at level 1_ of input expression with `foo` (see  [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html))

Answer (score 8):

What kglr posted, but a bit more "golfed"

```
data = {{49, 35, 14}, {64, 40, 16}, {81, 45, 18}};

{√#, ##2} & @@@ data
```

> ```
> {{7, 35, 14}, {8, 40, 16}, {9, 45, 18}}
> ```

Comment: I haver never seen this symbol. Looks good! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{49, 35, 14}, {64, 40, 16}, {81, 45, 18}};
```

Showing some of the newer functions

```
SubsetMap[Sqrt, {1}] /@ list

ReplaceAt[x_ :> Sqrt[x], {All, 1}] @ list

SequenceReplace[{{x_, y__}} :> {Sqrt[x], y}] @ list
```

All return

```
{{7, 35, 14}, {8, 40, 16}, {9, 45, 18}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{49, 35, 14}, {64, 40, 16}, {81, 45, 18}};
```

---

Using `Distribute`:

```
Distribute[data, Function[n, {Sqrt@n[[1]], Splice@n[[2 ;;]]}] /@ # &]
```

*Result*:

> {{7, 35, 14}, {8, 40, 16}, {9, 45, 18}}

Answer (score 2):

Sjoerd Smit has [posted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229052/106) a very neat method for applying a function to a matrix column:

```
data = {{49, 35, 14}, {64, 40, 16}, {81, 45, 18}};

Query[All,{1->(Sqrt[#]&)}]@data

(* {{7,35,14},{8,40,16},{9,45,18}} *)
```

In this instance, `Query` is using `MapAt` 'under the hood':

```
Query[All,{1->(Sqrt[#]&)}]//Normal

(* MapAt[Sqrt[#1]&,{All,1}] *)
```