# Applying a function to every item in a column of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

A problem that arises more often than I care for is that I want to modify specific elements nested lists.

Examples may be wanting to `add 1` to the second value, get the `Sqrt` of the third or wanting to add/change the `Unit` of the penultimate one. My current workaround is using `Table` to do so, which is not only untidy, but probably pretty inefficient, too. (I just downloaded a list that's 190k lines long, with 18 values a line. I'm not even gonna try that)

```
test = Table[{x, x + 1, x + 2, x + 3, x + 4, x + 5}, {x, 0, 10}];
Table[{test[[i, 1]], test[[i, 2]] + 1, Sqrt[test[[i, 3]]], Quantity[test[[i, 4]], "Meters"], test[[i, 5]], test[[i,6]]}, {i, 1, Length[test]}]
```

what I'd very much prefer is using `Replace all /.`

```
rule=**???**
test /. rule
```

I as I don't want to change every third element to a "static" value or something, I assume that I'd need to use Slots (`#`), but anything I can come up with like

```
rule = #[[2]] -> #[[2]] + 1
rule = #2 -> #2 + 1
```

will throw me an error. I'm sure there's a solution, and I'm sure more experienced people will look at this and see my obvious mistake (and lack of understanding of Slots), but I don't know, and would appreciate any suggestions.

*Edit:* I didn't intentionally drop the last element, and fixed it.

Comment: Try something like that:  ReplacePart[#, {2 -> #[[2]] + 1, 3 -> Sqrt[#[[3]]], 
    4 -> Quantity[#[[4]], "Meters"]}] & /@ test

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I think I even understand how the logic behind it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to apply different functions to different columns is with `Query`. This has the added advantage that columns you don't want to do anything with do not have to be specified explicitly. For example, to apply functions to the 1st and 3rd columns:

```
Query[All, {1 -> f, 3 -> g}] @ RandomInteger[10, {5, 4}] // TableForm
```

> [image]

This also works very well with data in the form of a list of associations.

Comment: `Query` seems very powerful and is especially way faster. Thank you, I wasn't aware of this, and I'll try to learn to use it.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a pure function `func1` with the desired transformation of various [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)s of an input n-tuple and use it with [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

```
func1 = {#[[1]], #[[2]] + 1, Sqrt @ #[[3]],  Quantity[#[[4]], "Meters"], #[[5]], #[[6]]} &;

Map[func] @ test
```

or define your function using [`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)s and use it with [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
func2 = {#, #2 + 1, Sqrt @ #3, Quantity[#4, "Meters"], #5, #6} &;

func2 @@@ test
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I wasn't aware of Map and Apply.

I just noticed a mistake I made above, that your solution also includes: The last element is dropped, because [[6]] is left out. 

 user18792 's solution elegantly circumvents that problem.

I will use your answer as a starting point to learn more about pure functions, Map and Apply

Comment: @Jonas, I thought you wanted to drop the last column.

Comment: No, I just made a mistake. I'll mark and edit it, if I find out how to.

Comment: @Jonas, welcome to mma.se. Thank you for the accept; but, if this were my question, I would have accepted Sjoerd's answer.  I suggest you consider unaccepting this answer and accepting Sjoerd's.

Answer (score 4):

One way of applying a function to a specific column of a matrix is to use  `Inner` (which may be thought of as a generalized form of `Dot`). (see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225507/106))

```
Inner[Times,test,ConstantArray[1,Length@test[[1]]],{#1,f@#2,##3}&]//TeXForm
```

$$
 \left(
             \begin{array}{cccccc}
              0 & f[1] & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
              1 & f[2] & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
              2 & f[3] & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
              3 & f[4] & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
              4 & f[5] & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
              5 & f[6] & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
              6 & f[7] & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
              7 & f[8] & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
              8 & f[9] & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
              9 & f[10] & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
              10 & f[11] & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
             \end{array}
             \right)
$$

For the requested modifications:

```
Inner[Times,test,ConstantArray[1,Length@test[[1]]],
       {#1,#2+1, Sqrt@#3, Quantity[#4, "meters"],##5}&
     ]//TeXForm
```

$$ \left(
             \begin{array}{cccccc}
              0 & 2 & \sqrt{2} & 3\text{m} & 4 & 5 \\
              1 & 3 & \sqrt{3} & 4\text{m} & 5 & 6 \\
              2 & 4 & 2 & 5\text{m} & 6 & 7 \\
              3 & 5 & \sqrt{5} & 6\text{m} & 7 & 8 \\
              4 & 6 & \sqrt{6} & 7\text{m} & 8 & 9 \\
              5 & 7 & \sqrt{7} & 8\text{m} & 9 & 10 \\
              6 & 8 & 2 \sqrt{2} & 9\text{m} & 10 & 11 \\
              7 & 9 & 3 & 10\text{m} & 11 & 12 \\
              8 & 10 & \sqrt{10} & 11\text{m} & 12 & 13 \\
              9 & 11 & \sqrt{11} & 12\text{m} & 13 & 14 \\
              10 & 12 & 2 \sqrt{3} & 13\text{m} & 14 & 15 \\
             \end{array}
             \right)
$$

---

If all that is required is to multiply each value in a column by a factor, then `Dot` is sufficient (and very fast).

For example, to multiply all values in column-2 by 100:

```
test.DiagonalMatrix[{1,100,1,1,1,1}]//TeXForm
```

$$\left(
             \begin{array}{cccccc}
              0 & 100 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
              1 & 200 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
              2 & 300 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
              3 & 400 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
              4 & 500 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
              5 & 600 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
              6 & 700 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
              7 & 800 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
              8 & 900 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
              9 & 1000 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
              10 & 1100 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
             \end{array}
             \right)
$$

---

```
test = Table[{x, x + 1, x + 2, x + 3, x + 4, x + 5}, {x, 0, 10}];
```

---

Comparison with the very neat [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229052/106) given by [Sjoerd Smit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit)

```
(Query[All, {2 -> (#+1&),3->Sqrt,4 ->(Quantity[#, "meters"]&)}]@test)===
Inner[Times,test,{1,1,1,1,1,1},{#1,#2+1,Sqrt@#3, Quantity[#4, "meters"],##5}&]
```

> True

Comment: > Inner[Times,test,ConstantArray[1,Length@test[[1]]],
       {#1,#2+1, Sqrt@#3, Quantity[#4, "meters"],#5}&
     ]//TeXForm
Why do I need to multiply test with the `ConstantArray` First? Is it only because `Inner` needs two matrices, and that Array is a neutral element of `Times`?

Comment: As I understand it, and from the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html), `Inner[f,list1,list2,g] `  "is a generalization of _Dot_ in which _f_ plays the role of multiplication and _g_ of addition. For example, to multiply the second column of _test_ by 100 using _Inner_: `Inner[Times, test,{1,100,1,1,1,1},List]`. And, say, to multiply column-1 by 100 and do your requested modifications (one of several ways): `Inner[Times,test,{100,1,1,1,1,1},{#1,#2+1,Sqrt@#3, Quantity[#4, "meters"],#5}&]//MatrixForm`

Comment: `Dot` can be very 'handy'.  If you have a list of {x,y} values and you just want to multiply the _y_ values by 10:  `values.{{1,0},{0,10}}` (but you probably already know that).

Comment: I didn't, but that hasn't cropped up yet, and now I do :). And the "requested modifications" are more examples that would be the same form of things that came up in the past. What I need currently is `UnixTime`, but if `Sqrt` and `Quantity` work, then most of what I can think of, will, too.
 - 
The reason I asked about the `ConstantArray` is, that to me it seems like it doesn't "do" anything, because it's the neutral element. From the docs and my meddling I figured, that I need that, but it seems like a roundabout way. A placeholder. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: IMO [Query](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229052/106) , as shown by [Sjoerd Smit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit), is 'the way to go'

Comment: The second list (or 'ConstantArray' list) in _Inner_ may be thought of as being equivalent to the diagonal matrix in _Dot_.  If `v={1,100,1,1,1,1};`, all of the following multiply the second row of _test_ by 100 (but _Dot_ is much faster than _Inner_): 
 `test.DiagonalMatrix[v] == Inner[Times, test, DiagonalMatrix[v]] == Inner[Times, test, v, List]== Inner[Times, test, {1,1,1,1,1,1}, {#1,100 #2,##3}&]==Inner[Times, test, {1,4,1,1,1,1}, {#1,25 #2,##3}&]`

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[0];

list = RandomInteger[10, {3, 4}];
```

One function applied to two columns

```
MapAt[f, {{All, 2}, {All, 4}}] @ list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Two functions applied to two columns

```
MapAt[g, {All, 4}] @ MapAt[f, {All, 2}] @ list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Fold`:**

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[10, {3, 4}];
Fold[MapAt[First@#2, #1, {All, Last@#2}] &, 
  list, {{f, 2}, {g, 4}}] // MatrixForm
```

or

```
Fold[SubsetMap[Map[First@#2], #1, {All, Last@#2}] &, list, {{f, 
   2}, {g, 4}}] // MatrixForm
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];

list = RandomInteger[10, {3, 4}];
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and playing with `ReplacePart`, we can apply one function to two columns as follows:

```
p1 = Array[{#, 2} &, {Length@list}];
p2 = Array[{#, 4} &, {Length@list}];

r1 = Thread[p1 -> f /@ Extract[#, p1]] &;
r2 = Thread[p2 -> f /@ Extract[#, p2]] &;

ReplacePart[#, Union @@ {r1@#, r2@#}] &@list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Two functions applied to two columns:

```
r1 = Thread[p1 -> f /@ Extract[#, p1]] &;
r2 = Thread[p2 -> g /@ Extract[#, p2]] &;

ReplacePart[#, Union @@ {r1@#, r2@#}] &@list // MatrixForm
```

[image]