# How to multiply first element of each row by a number?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I create list2 from list1?

```
   list1 = {{a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {c, {c1, c2, c3}}}
   list2 = {{a*4, {a1, a2, a3}}, {b*4, {b1, b2, b3}}, {c*4, {c1, c2, 
    c3}}}
```

Thank you

Comment: p=1; list1/.{   { _  ,{x_y_.z_} }   :> {  { 4 a, 4 b , 4c }[[p++]]   ,  {x, y, z}  }  }

Comment: Try `MapAt[4*# &, list1, {All, 1}]`

Comment: Try this: `list1 /. {a_, b_List} -> {4 a, b}`, Have fun!

Comment: IMO, future visitors to this site might appreciate the above three comments being posted as answers.

Comment: Related: (i) [Applying a function to every item in a column of a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229048/106) and (ii) [What is a good way of perfoming operations on specified columns of a table with many columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230854/106)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also

```
ReplaceAt[list1, x_:> 4 x, {All,1}]

(* {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}} *)
```

**(2)**

In addition, it [has been shown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229052/106) by [Sjoerd Smit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit) that a function may be applied to a matrix column using [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html)

```
Query[All, {1 -> (4 #&)}]@list1

(* {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}} *)
```

In this case, `Query` apparently uses [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) 'in the background'

```
Query[All, {1 -> (4 #&)}]//Normal

(* MapAt[4 #1 & , {All, 1}] *)
```

(The use of [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) has been suggested by [platomaniac](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/240/platomaniac) in a comment)

Answer (score 6):

#### 1. [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html)

```
list2 = SubsetMap[4 # &, {All, 1}]@list1
```

> ```
> {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}
> ```

#### 2. [`ApplyTo (//=)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html)

```
list2 = list1;
list2[[All, 1]] //= 4 # &;
list2
```

> ```
>  {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}
> ```

#### 3. [`TimesBy (*=)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimesBy.html)

```
list2 = list1;
list2[[All, 1]] *= 4;
list2
```

> ```
> {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}
> ```

#### 4. [`MapApply (@@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html)

```
list2 = {4 #, ##2} & @@@ list1
```

> ```
> {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Another way using `Part`:

```
{4*#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ list1

(*{{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}*)
```

Also:

```
Function[{x}, Transpose@{4 x[[All, 1]], x[[All, 2]]}]@list1
(*{{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = {{a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {c, {c1, c2, c3}}}

{4, 1} # & /@ list1

MapThread[Times, {Table[{4, 1}, Length@list1], list1}]

Inner[Times, list1, {4, 1}, List]

Inner[Times, {4, 1}, #, List] & /@ list1
```

> {{4 a, {a1, a2, a3}}, {4 b, {b1, b2, b3}}, {4 c, {c1, c2, c3}}}